# Javascript Console with Firebug

Tags: javascript

How can I debug the following code:

```
var x = 213;
console.log(x);
```

When I run it I get blank display. I'd like the debugger to show: "213".
Where do I get the "Javascript console"?

Comment: F12 works for most browsers to open the developer tools

Comment: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers

Comment: Did you find out how it works? Do you need more help?

Answer (score 2):

Open firebug, e.g. using F12. Then click on the "console" tab...

---

You don't need Firebug to access the console by the way. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> will open Firefox's builtin developer tools which also have a console.

However, you shouldn't open both at the same time. If you do that, you might see the console output only in one of the two consoles.

---

Also, on [webmasters.stackexchange.com](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/77337/2854) there's a post explaining how to access the console in various browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to press `F12` to open the console/developer tools. in chrome, firefox and Internet explorer.

Comment: IE has the same shortcut